# Fetching the comment history for a work item in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, sdk

In most defect trackers there is a comment history associated with a ticket/incident/issue/work item.

I wish to get this same information from TFS via the SDK for a work item - ideally:

- Who created the comment.
- The text of the comment.
- Who last updated/edited the comment (if that's event possible in TFS?)

I have determined that a WorkItem has a collection of revisions availabe via the "Revisions" property, and that you can loop through each revision - but a revision does not have a "History" property where I assume I could find the comment created by the user.  Also I don't believe it's compulsory to record a comment with each change - so I suspect I will need to ignore revisions that don't have any history property information?

[Revisions Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.revisions(VS.80).aspx)

Any thoughts on the best way to fetch this "comment history" information for a work item in TFS - is the revisions list the correct way, or should I be using some other part of the API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to fetch the comment history you need to access the "History" property on the Work Item revision.

[WorkItem.History Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.history.aspx)

Obviously the current (latest) version of the work item will have this field as empty, but historical revision comments will be there.

[TFS: Getting workitem history from the api](http://adallow.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/tfs-getting-workitem-history-from-the-api/)

The "History" displayed on a work item in Team Explorer is built by looping through the Revissions and displaying both the fields that were changed and the text in the "History" property

Comment: Darn it Martin, you're beating me to the punch answering these questions! +1 to you!