# How can I implement tf history command in C#?

Tags: c#, tfs

I would like to implement the following command using TFS programming API:

```
tf history /stopafter:1 /version:W /recursive /format:detailed /noprompt .
```

I have some code, but it tries to inspect local workspace info and there is none. So, I am back to nothing.

How is it done?

Comment: What code have you tried?
Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.history.aspx
and also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508000/fetching-the-comment-history-for-a-work-item-in-tfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`VersionControlServer.QueryHistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736442.aspx):

```
versionControlServer.QueryHistory(
    serverPath,
    VersionSpec.Latest,
    0,
    RecursionType.Full,                  /* recursive */
    null,
    null,
    new WorkspaceVersionSpec(workspace), /* /version:W */
    1,                                   /* /stopafter:1 */
    true,                                /* /format:detailed */
    true,
    true,
    false);
```