# How to get the TFS discussion comments from TFS api using c#

Tags: c#, tfs

Am working on the TFS work item to get the comments ,latest added comment date and first added comment date to store in database. Can anybody please assist me on achieving this.

```
    foreach (Revision r in RqInfo.Revisions)
    {
        foreach (Field f in r.Fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Name, f.Value);
        }
    }
```

Have tried above code section, it gives all the Changed Date including for the attached link. I need only for comments from history. Please assist me.

This `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client` namespace used but getting the  comments for particular work item is not able find.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: foreach (Revision r in RqInfo.Revisions)
                {
                    foreach (Field f in r.Fields)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(f.Name, f.Value);

                    }
                }

Comment: @VasukiHebbar please don't add details in comments, edit the question

Comment: Above code line gives me all the data including attached link, but i want Changed Date only for comments from history, not for the links.

Comment: @WojtekT Please assist me is there any way to get only comments from history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check only the `System.History` field. That was considered here: [Fetching the comment history for a work item in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508000/fetching-the-comment-history-for-a-work-item-in-tfs)

Here is an example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    string historyField = "System.History";
    string changedDateField = "System.ChangedDate";
    string changedByField = "System.ChangedBy";

    WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore("<your_server_url>/tfs/DefaultCollection");

    WorkItem wi = store.GetWorkItem(your_id);

    foreach (Revision rev in wi.Revisions)
    {

        if (rev.Fields[historyField].Value.ToString() != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} says: \n{2}",
                rev.Fields[changedDateField].Value,
                rev.Fields[changedByField].Value,
                rev.Fields[historyField].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This i have tried , am getting all the data but i need only Discussion Only Tab in the history field. Can this be possible?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for :)